# Merging multiple JSON objects into one JSON object

Tags: json, python-3.x, merge

I am doing multiple requests to a REST service and getting JSON data back from each request. What I want to do is merge all of those JSON objects (hoping I am using the right terminology) into one object. How do I do that?

```
minCount = 1
maxCount = 1000
masterJson = {}
for x in range(36):
    params = {'f': 'json', 'where': 'OBJECTID>='+str(minCount)+'and OBJECTID<='+str(maxCount), 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'true'}
    r = requests.get('https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query', params)

    cslfJson = r.json()
    masterJson.update(cslfJson)

    for item in cslfJson['features']:
        objCount = item['attributes']['OBJECTID']

        if minCount < objCount:
            break
        else:
        minCount = minCount + maxCount
        maxCount = maxCount + 1000
```

Essentially, its the cslfJson variables (JSON obj) that I want to combine into one cslfJson object variable.

Comment: Every time you run masterJson.update(cslfJson) the data in masterJson will be replaced, is it intentional?

Comment: No. That is part of the issue. I want it to add each iteration of the cslfJson data, not update it with the new data.

Comment: why don't you use masterJson = [] and do masterJson.append(cslfJson) to collect all responses?

Comment: I actually considered that earlier. Would I then be able to convert that masterJson list into a dictionary/JSON object? Doesn't json.dump() do that?

Comment: You should be able to json.dump() anything that is a valid json.
You can test json here https://jsoneditoronline.org/.
A list of objects is a valid json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the memory JSON objects are treated like a `dict` so treat each JSON obj as a `dict`.

```
masterJson = {}
masterJson['JSON1'] = cslfJson
masterJson['JSON2'] = cslfJson
```

If you need to write a .json file, you can just pass the whole `dict` as argument to the JSON writers.

Comment: This essentially works. However, adding the new name for each separate object complicates things a bit because of processing further down the line (these objects are used to create spatial features in GIS in a later stage).

Comment: you can use a variable as the key `masterJson[variable] = cslfJson`. just the keys should be unique.

Comment: I opened another question that may resolve my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989564/updating-a-master-json-object-by-adding-data-to-a-subobject