# Updating a 'master' JSON object by adding data to a subobject

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, iteration, updates

Lets say I have a list of JSON objects:

```
list = [{"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 2, "Zone": "A"}, "geo": {"x": 10, "y": 20}}]},{"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 3, "Zone": "D"}, "geo": {"x": 21, "y": 8}}]},{"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 5, "Zone": "C"}, "geo": {"x": 15, "y": 10}}]}]
```

I want to iterate through this list and have a single 'Master' json object:

```
masterJson = {}
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

The problem here is that I don't want to just 'update' the masterJson object with every new iteration. Essentially, the subobjects "Name" and "Date" will always be the same. What I want to do is add to the "features" subobject list only so that in the masterJson object it looks like this:

```
masterJson = {"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 2, "Zone": "A"}, "geo": {"x": 10, "y": 20}}, {"attributes": {"OID": 3, "Zone": "D"}, "geo": {"x": 21, "y": 8}}, {"attributes": {"OID": 5, "Zone": "C"}, "geo": {"x": 15, "y": 10}}]}
```

My current idea is to have something like the following, but I can't get it to quite work for me. How do I achieve this?

```
list = [{"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 2, "Zone": "A"}, "geo": {"x": 10, "y": 20}}]},{"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 3, "Zone": "D"}, "geo": {"x": 21, "y": 8}}]},{"Name": "NY", "Date": "12/2008", "features": [{"attributes": {"OID": 5, "Zone": "C"}, "geo": {"x": 15, "y": 10}}]}]
masterJson = list[0]
for item in list:
    for item["features"]:
        masterJson["features"] = (item["features"])

print(masterJson)
```

Another variation:

```
masterJson = list[0]
for item in list:
    for k in item:
        if k not in masterJson["features"]
            masterJson["features"] = (item["features"])

print(masterJson)
```

Note: The results seem to be `"features": "features"`

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe because someone has undone his/her vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop bit adds the features part in the `masterJson` dict.

```
tempList = []
masterJson = {}
masterJson['Name'] = list[0]['Name']
masterJson['Date'] = list[0]['Date']
for item in list:
    tempList.extend(item['features'])
masterJson['features']=tempList
```

before using this part, add the `Name` and `Date` part to the `masterJson` dict and you will have the structure you require.
`tempList` is a temporary list to hold the different `features` dict.
cheers.

Comment: I'm a little confused; what is `tempList`? Do I define it somewhere as just an empty dictionary? Also, I'm making masterJson =  list[0], so it starts out with `Name`, `Date`, and the `first features`. So, I am just extending `features`? Is that what you mean

Comment: ahh sorry. I edited my answer to include the initialization of `tempList` and `masterJson`. Do not add `list[0]` to `masterJson`. Rather add the `Name` and `Date` portion separately to `masterJson`. I would suggest take the option of writing everything for a dict item once than choosing to append later. It makes your code wayyy simpler.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch! :-)

Comment: In my opinion, just have a look at some [Data Structure Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-structures-python). It might help to learn.